# Searchable listview for partial word search - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I want to implement a filter function in listview with search box for partial word search. I have made the following search mechanism, how do I get partial word search functionality?

Eg. If I search for "stackover..", stackoverflow appears but if I search for "tackover.." stackoverflow doesn't appear, I need it to search for partial matches in words.

Here's my code

```
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            textlength = et.getText().length();
            array_sort.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < actorsList.size(); i++)
            {
                String nama = actorsList.get(i).getName();
                if (textlength <= nama.length())
                {
                    if (et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) nama.subSequence(0, textlength)) )
                    {
                        array_sort.add(actorsList.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
            if (array_sort.isEmpty())
            {
                textView.setText(R.string.empty);
            }
            else
            {
                textView.setText("");
            }
            adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, array_sort);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
filterEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.filter);
filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {  

    }  
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {  
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
    }  
};
```

The adapter must implement Filterable

```
        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {

            if(filter == null)
                filter = new CheeseFilter();
            return filter;
        }
```

And the filter class:

```
    public class CheeseFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults newFilterResults = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {


                ArrayList<String> auxData = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                    if (data.get(i).toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                        auxData.add(data.get(i));
                }

                newFilterResults.count = auxData.size();
                newFilterResults.values = auxData;
            } else {

                newFilterResults.count = data.size();
                newFilterResults.values = data;
            }

            return newFilterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            ArrayList<String> resultData = new ArrayList<String>();

            resultData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;

            EfficientAdapter adapter = new EfficientAdapter(context, resultData);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This page has working example of what you are looking for 
http://learningsolo.com/android-text-search-filter-with-textwatcher-in-listview-example/

Add search box in app bar layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<!-- To add Search Text box to action bar -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            <EditText android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/searchProjectTxt" android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:singleLine="true" android:hint="Search Here..." />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Then add TextWatcher on "searchProjectTxt" to add filter

```
EditText searchTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchProjectTxt);
searchTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                filter(cs.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    void filter(String text){
        List<ProjectsVo> temp = new ArrayList();
        for(ProjectsVo d: projectListCache){
            if(d.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())){
                temp.add(d);
            }
        }
        projectList.clear();
        projectList.addAll(temp);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```